# Number of states $\Omega(E)$ derivation (Reif problem 2.4)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

Problem 2.4 from Reif's "*Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics*":

> Consider an isolated system consisting of a large number $N$ of virtually non-interacting localized (not translating) particles of spin $1/2$. Each particle has magnetic moment $\mu$ which can point either parallel or antiparallel to an applied magnetic field $H$. The energy of the system is $E=−\left(n_1−n_2\right)\mu H$ where $n_1$ is the number of particles with spin parallel and $n_2$ is the number of particles with spin antiparallel to $H$.
>
> a) Consider the energy range $E\rightarrow E+\delta E$ where $\delta E$ is very small compared to $E$ but is microscopically large, i.e., $\delta E \gg \mu H$. What is the total number of states, $\Omega(E)$, of the system lying in this energy range?

The solution to the number of states is,$$
\Omega(E) =\frac{f(n_1)\delta E}{2\mu H}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
f(n_1) = \frac{N!}{n_1!n_2!}\,.
$$

I understand the $f\left(n_1\right)$ term, but I'm confused as to how the author got the $2\mu H$ term in $\Omega (E)$. Please help me understand this derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy change of a dipole in a magnetic field is $2\mu H$. So the larger this energy is, the fewer the number of states within a certain energy range.